# Getting the correct centering of frame in graphics package

Tags: java, graphics

so I'm having trouble centering a frame so that my whole graph is on the screen. Currently, when I run my program, the x values on the coordinate system are the correct range but I can barely see my graph because the frame is centered hundreds of pixels above where the graph is drawn. Here is my code:

```
public static int startx = 1;
public static int endx = 500;
static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

int WIDTH = 0;  
int HEIGHT = 0;


public GraphSigma(int WIDTH, int HEIGHT) {
    this.WIDTH = WIDTH;
    this.HEIGHT = HEIGHT;
}

// Draw your spiral here!!!
// You'll need to use a FOR loop to calculate the
// points on the spiral


public void paintSigma(Graphics g){

    int prevX=startx;
    int prevY=Sigma.Sigma(startx);
     Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.translate(0, Sigma.Sigma(endx));
    g2.scale(1,-1);
    if (endx-startx < 50)
        for (int i = startx; i <= endx; i++) {
            int x = i;
            int y = Sigma.Sigma(i);
            g.drawLine(0+prevX, 0+prevY, x, y);
            prevX=x;
            prevY=y;

            };
    if (51 < endx-startx && endx-startx < 300)
        for (int i = startx; i <= endx; i+=2) {
        int x = i;
        int y = Sigma.Sigma(i);
        g.drawLine(0+prevX, 0+prevY, x, y);
        prevX=x;
        prevY=y;

        };
        if (301 < endx-startx  && endx-startx < 1000)
        for (int i = startx; i <= endx; i+=4) {
            int x = i;
            int y = Sigma.Sigma(i);
            g.drawLine(0+prevX, 0+prevY, x, y);
            prevX=x;
            prevY=y;

        };
        if (1000<endx-startx)
            for (int i = startx; i <= endx; i+=10) {
                int x = i;
                int y = Sigma.Sigma(i);
                g.drawLine(0+prevX, 0+prevY, x, y);
                prevX=x;
                prevY=y;

                };

}

// This special method is automatically called when the scene needs to be drawn.
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    paintSigma(g);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Graphics window size

    int WINDOW_WIDTH = endx-startx+20;
    int WINDOW_HEIGHT = endx;

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    frame.setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);

    frame.setTitle("Sigma Function");

    GraphSigma d = new GraphSigma(endx-startx+20, Sigma.Sigma(endx));
    frame.add(d);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

}

The sigma method I am calling up is in a different class, here is the code for that:
public class Sigma {

```
static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

public static int Sigma(int s){
    int a = 0;
    for(int i=1;i<=s;i++){
        if(s%i==0)
            a = a + i;

    }
    return a;

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Please enter the number you want to perform the sigma function on");
    int s = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print(Sigma.Sigma(s) +" is the sum of all the divisors of your input" ); 
    }

}
```

I honestly don't know how to center this correctly, am I missing a method? I've been messing with variables and they don't seem to change how the frame is centered.
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

First, let's clean up your code, then I'll show you where you went wrong.

**Sigma Class**

Here's my version of the Sigma class.

1) You don't name a method the same as the class name.  I changed your method name to calculateSigma.

2) When you open a Scanner, you close it after you're finished.

3) Never define and open the scanner variable in the class like you did.  Especially as many times as you call the calculateSigma method.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sigma {

    public static int calculateSigma(int s) {
        int a = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= s; i++) {
            if (s % i == 0)
                a = a + i;
        }
        return a;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input   = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the number you want " +
                "to perform the sigma function on");
        int s = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print(Sigma.calculateSigma(s)
                + " is the sum of all the divisors of your input");
        input.close();
    }

}
```

**GraphSigma Class**

Here's my version of the GraphSigma class.

**You always invoke a Swing application on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT).  This prevents problems.**

I couldn't see the graphing problem at first, so I added a debug display method for the drawLine methods.  This showed me that you were drawing the lines between (1,1) and (497,576).

With this information, I focused in on the translate and scale methods in your drawing code.

The translate method moves the origin of the graph.

The scale method translates the calculated coordinates into the graphing coordinates by multiplying the calculated coordinates by a factor to get the graphing coordinates.

The first thing I did to fix the problem is change the numbers I used to call the translate method to move the origin of the graph to the lower left hand corner of the JPanel.

The second thing I did to fix the problem is figure out the scaling factor so that the graph would fit in the JPanel.  The debugging information gave me confidence that my scaling factor was correct.

I left the debugging code in the class so you (and others) can see one way you can debug a Java class and figure out for yourself what's going wrong.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class GraphSigma extends JPanel {

    public static boolean   DEBUG   = false;

    public static int       startx  = 1;
    public static int       endx    = 500;
    static Scanner          input   = new Scanner(System.in);

    int                     WIDTH   = 0;
    int                     HEIGHT  = 0;

    public GraphSigma(int WIDTH, int HEIGHT) {
        this.WIDTH = WIDTH;
        this.HEIGHT = HEIGHT;
    }

    // Draw your spiral here!!!
    // You'll need to use a FOR loop to calculate the
    // points on the spiral

    public void paintSigma(Graphics g) {

        int prevX = startx;
        int prevY = Sigma.calculateSigma(startx);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        if (DEBUG) {
            System.out.println("Sigma of endx: " 
                    + Sigma.calculateSigma(endx));
        }
        g2.translate(0, this.getHeight());
        g2.scale(1, -((double) this.getHeight()) / 
                Sigma.calculateSigma(endx));
        if (endx - startx < 50)
            for (int i = startx; i <= endx; i++) {
                int x = i;
                int y = Sigma.calculateSigma(i);
                if (DEBUG) {
                    debugOutput(0 + prevX, 0 + prevY, x, y);
                }
                g.drawLine(0 + prevX, 0 + prevY, x, y);
                prevX = x;
                prevY = y;

            }
        ;
        if (51 < endx - startx && endx - startx < 300)
            for (int i = startx; i <= endx; i += 2) {
                int x = i;
                int y = Sigma.calculateSigma(i);
                if (DEBUG) {
                    debugOutput(0 + prevX, 0 + prevY, x, y);
                }
                g.drawLine(0 + prevX, 0 + prevY, x, y);
                prevX = x;
                prevY = y;

            }
        ;
        if (301 < endx - startx && endx - startx < 1000)
            for (int i = startx; i <= endx; i += 4) {
                int x = i;
                int y = Sigma.calculateSigma(i);
                if (DEBUG) {
                    debugOutput(0 + prevX, 0 + prevY, x, y);
                }
                g.drawLine(0 + prevX, 0 + prevY, x, y);
                prevX = x;
                prevY = y;

            }
        ;
        if (1000 < endx - startx)
            for (int i = startx; i <= endx; i += 10) {
                int x = i;
                int y = Sigma.calculateSigma(i);
                if (DEBUG) {
                    debugOutput(0 + prevX, 0 + prevY, x, y);
                }
                g.drawLine(0 + prevX, 0 + prevY, x, y);
                prevX = x;
                prevY = y;

            }
        ;

    }

    private void debugOutput(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
        System.out.println("Line drawn from (" + x1 + "," + y1 + ") to (" + x2
                + "," + y2 + ").");
    }

    // This special method is automatically called when the scene needs to be
    // drawn.
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        paintSigma(g);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Graphics window size
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                createGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createGUI() {
        int WINDOW_WIDTH = endx - startx + 20;
        int WINDOW_HEIGHT = endx;

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        frame.setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);

        frame.setTitle("Sigma Function");

        GraphSigma d = new GraphSigma(endx - startx + 20,
                Sigma.calculateSigma(endx));
        frame.add(d);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

}
```